# Where can I find a comparison of Distributed (and Offline?) Issue Trackers?

Tags: comparison, issue-tracking

I'm looking for a fairly recent in depth comparison of currently available Distributed and hopefully Offline Issue Trackers.

I've found this http://heapkeeper-heap.github.com/hh/thread_298.html#post-summary-hh-1076 which is decently recent and covers a number of solutions, but isn't up to date and IMO wasn't as researched as it could have been, so I'm looking for similar comparisons.

Full disclosure, I've become the primary maintainer of the TicGit distributed issue tracking system http://github.com/jeffWelling/ticgit .  I'm looking for a comparison to see if I'm reinventing the wheel with my development with TicGit.  I want a distributed offline issue tracking system, which in a perfect world would be written in Ruby, and which supports a web interface.  The web interface could be a daemon or it could just be HTML files I publish somewhere.  Ticgit already does these things, but if someone else out there does them better or has the same feature list with a larger community..

I found this comment http://github.com/blog/411-github-issue-tracker#comment-1722 which comes from someone knowledgeable on the subject, which says storing tickets in git causes you to lose a lot of functionality, but doesn't elaborate.  I don't understand why that would cause a loss of functionality.

If you can't suggest a comparison, whats your favorite Distributed Issue Tracker and why? :)

Comment: The comparison you mentioned (written by me :) ) has been updated and posted on Stack Overflow a year ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186628/textbased-issue-tracker-todo-list-for-git/2187005#2187005 (Still outdated, but a bit less outdated than the version above.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186628/textbased-issue-tracker-todo-list-for-git/2187005#2187005

Comment: The link is broken.